# Trying to figure out how to output a phone number in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to input a phone number and print it out in this format (888)999-1111 format but when i am trying to print it out i get some weird output that is not what i am expecting to get back out. I am printing out the values of phone both in the input and in the print function bt they are different. The one in the input function is correct but it isnt correct in the print function. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
int phoneInput(void)
{
    long int phone = 0;

    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no speaces: ");
    scanf("%ld", &phone);
    printf("test : %ld", phone);
return phone;
}

int printPhone(long int phone)
{
    int i = 10; //the number of digits in the phone
    char output[11];

    printf("Test: %ld", phone);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
    while (phone > 0)
    {
            output[i] = phone % 10;
            phone /= 10;
    }
    }

    printf("- Phone number: (");
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }

    printf(")");
    i = 3;
    for(i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }
    i = 6;
    printf("-");
    for(i = 6; i < 10; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `output[i] = phone % 10;`, try `output[i]+='0';` to convert from `int` to the character representing that digit. Or better yet, instead of reading in an integer and manually turning it into a string, just read the input in as a string. Also, please post your `main` function, too.

Comment: you can make int output[11] instead of char output[11], or do like the comment above but changes the printf from %d to %c

Comment: `output[11]` looks small.  How about [983-49552-072886-117309-5773](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_longest_phone_number)?

Comment: "when i am trying to print it out i get some weird output" --> it is more informative to post the _exact_ output received rather than only describe it.

Answer (score 8):

The only reason you'd need to store a value as an `int`, a `long int`, or another numeric type is if you had to do arithmetic on it (unless it's required by a homework assignment specification). Don't be fooled by the fact that a phone number is composed of numbers - it makes most sense to be stored as a string!

If you *can* store the phone number as a string, you should:

```
char *phoneInput(void)
{
    static char phone[100];
    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no spaces: ");
    fgets(phone, 100, stdin);
    return phone;
}
```

Once you have that, it's easier to control how it is printed:

```
printf("(%.3s) %.3s-%.4s\n", phone, phone + 3, phone + 6);
```

Comment: This answer well identifies a major input/design issue, yet OP's `while (phone > 0)
    {
            output[i] = phone % 10;
            phone /= 10;
    }` is seriously an error too.

Answer (score 2):

Sarah, first of all I would scan phone number as string, it is easier to do it that way. Another reason to scan it as string `long int` might not be sufficient enough, on some platforms long is 32 bits. But if you require 'long int` the best  way would be:

```
 printf ("(%ld)", number / 10000000); // prints area code (xxx)
 printf (" %ld-", (number / 1000) % 1000); // prints xxx-
 printf ("%ld\n", number % 10000); // prints xxxx\n
```

another way would be:

```
fscanf( stdin, " %3s%3s%4s", areacode, zone, number);
printf("(%s) %s-%s\n", areacode, zone, number);
```

Comment: `long` may be only 32-bit. Insufficient for OP's `(888)999-1111`

Comment: @chucks thanks for your input I really appreciate it. Now that I think about it Cisco phone that I use every day uses 16bit processor. :)

Comment: "on some platforms long is 32 or 16 bits long" --> `long` is _always_ at least 32-bit (C requirement), even on 16-bit, 8-bit or [1-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) processors

Comment: @chux I edited it again but I think that Cisco is one of those companies that does not give a damn about C standard.

Comment: That's OK if Cisco is not compliant - their choice.  It simply means that such a compiler is not a C compiler, just a C-like compiler and its issues are less relevant to this C-tagged post.

Comment: LOL cisco phones are funny story they do minimum in C and rest is all Java, that is why my 10 years PC running linux boots faster than does cisco phone.

Answer (score 2):

In your existing code, the problem lies in the loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
while (phone > 0)
{
        output[i] = phone % 10;
        phone /= 10;
}
}
```

Your inner loop will keep executing without incrementing `i` causing the same position in the array to be written again and again.

```
i = 9;
do
{
        output[i] = (phone % 10) + '0';
        phone /= 10;
        i--;
}while((phone > 0) && (i >= 0));
```

Please use `"%c"` in the printf while printing `output`.

---

> List of issues in the code posted by OP. These are just issues in the
>   code posted by OP. The logic can be done in many other ways, but, this
>   answer purely focuses on issues in OP's code as-is:
>
> - `phoneInput` function should return `long int` instead of `int`
> - `for and while loop` - Two loops are not needed. This is the main error. This causes same position in array to be overwritten each time.
> - Loop counter for array position starts from 0, causing digits to be written in reverse order in the array
> - Since, you are using a char array, store and print char instead of int.

---

**Complete code with issues fixed (as per OP's original code):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long int phoneInput(void)
{
    long int phone = 0;

    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no spaces: ");
    scanf("%ld", &phone);
    printf("test : %ld\n", phone);

    return phone;
}

int printPhone(long int phone)
{
    int i = 10; //the number of digits in the phone
    char output[11];

    memset(output, '0', sizeof(output));

    printf("Test: %ld\n", phone);

    i = 9;
    do
    {
       output[i] = (phone % 10) + '0';
       phone /= 10;
       i--;

    }while( (phone > 0) && (i >= 0));


    printf("- Phone number: (");
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            printf("%c", output[i]);
    }


    printf(")");
    i = 3;
    for(i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    {
            printf("%c", output[i]);
    }
    i = 6;
    printf("-");
    for(i = 6; i < 10; i++)
    {
            printf("%c", output[i]);
    }

return 0;
}

void main()
{
  long int phone;

  phone = phoneInput();
  printPhone(phone);

}
```

**Output:**

```
Input the politicians phone number with no spaces: 8889991111
test : 8889991111
Test: 8889991111
- Phone number: (888)999-1111
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please leave a comment, so that I can improve the answer?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but what you're doing is assigning digits into `output`, which in OP's code is an array of `char` (should convert to textual digit representation)

Comment: NMDV, This answer does correctly point out a serious problem in OP's code.  Others important ones exist too.

Comment: @GovindParmar, Thanks! Have edited the code. I just wanted to point out the key error in the OP's code. But, I do agree that I should have fixed this too.

Comment: @chux, Thanks for your comment. I agree. I just focused on the main error causing the values in output to go wrong.

Comment: Note that the `while((phone > 0) && (i < 10))` will prevent printing anything for the "Operator" `0`.  Maybe a `do {} while ();` instead?

Comment: @chux, Thanks for your comments. I have now added the complete fixed code. Thanks for helping me improve the answer.

Comment: @GovingParmar, Thanks for your comments again. I have now added the complete fixed code. Thanks for helping me improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A phone number should be stored as `country`, `area`, `subscriber`.

The example you gave would be `1 888 9991111`

And note that any leading `00` for a country number is actually *the local method of instructing the switch to dial an international number*. In Spain it used to be `9` for a long time. The generic identification for international number dialing is now `+`.

See also https://www.internationalcitizens.com/international-calling-codes/

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes to your code. Please take a look.

```
long long int phoneInput(void)
{
    long long int phone = 0;

    printf("Input the politicians phone number with no speaces: ");
    scanf("%lld", &phone);
    printf("test : %lld", phone);
return phone;
}

int printPhone(long long int phone)
{
    int i = 10; //the number of digits in the phone
    char output[11];

    printf("Test: %lld", phone);

    i = 9;     // removed for loop that was unnecessary.
    while (phone > 0)
    {
            output[i] = phone % 10;
            phone /= 10;
            i--;   
    }

    printf("- Phone number: (");
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }

    printf(")");
    i = 3;
    for(i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }
    i = 6;
    printf("-");
    for(i = 6; i < 10; i++)
    {
            printf("%d", output[i]);
    }

return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long long int n = phoneInput();
    printPhone(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

void printTelephoneNumber(vector phoneNum) {
string phonePad[10] {
"000", "111", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PRS", "TUV", "WXY"
};

```
size_t PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH = phoneNum.size();
size_t LETTERS_PER_KEY = 3;
size_t maxcount = (size_t )pow(LETTERS_PER_KEY, PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH);

// Could have used: colIndex[PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH] = {0};
vector<int> letterIndex(PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH, 0);   // Use either name: colIndex or charIndex

for(int count=0; count<maxcount; count++) {
    // print string
    string str = "";
    for(int i=0; i<PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH; i++) {
        str += phonePad[phoneNum[i]][letterIndex[i]];
    }
    cout << str << endl;
    
    // Update next letter (column) indicies
    int nextCount = count + 1;   // next count
    size_t i = PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH - 1;
    do {
        letterIndex[i] = nextCount % LETTERS_PER_KEY;
        nextCount = nextCount / LETTERS_PER_KEY;
        i--;
    } while(nextCount > 0);
}
```

}

Algorithm: There are 3^n combinations for n digits phone number. examples: phoneNum[n] = {2,3,4} => 3^3 = 27. Use extra space for tracking letters in a digit => letterIndex[PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH]

Answer (score -1):

```
while (phone > 0)
{
        output[i++] = (phone % 10) + '0';
        phone /= 10;
}
```

and

```
printf("%c", output[i]);
```

are the changes that need to be made in your code to make it work.

The first change (`+ '0'`) is to convert from `int` to `char`.
The second one is because you want to print a char and not an int.

I advise you to check the manual of [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand better.

Comment: Your loop doesn't increment the value of `i`, so it will keep writing to the same index in `output`